# How to go to other coordinates with GoogleMap?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have managed to find my current location with GoogleMap in the following way:

```js
  @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(actMapa, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Mensaje.mensajeSimple(getString(R.string.msg_error_ubicacion), getString(R.string.msg_aceptar), actMapa);

        }
        else{
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
            Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (null != myLocation) {
                longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
                latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

                LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation));

                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    addressActMapa = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    obtainedAddress = addressActMapa.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    /***
                    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                    String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
                    */
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Mensaje.mensajeSimple(getString(R.string.msg_error_obtener_direccion) + " " + e.getMessage(), getString(R.string.msg_aceptar), actMapa);
                }
            }
            else{
                Mensaje.mensajeSimple(getString(R.string.msg_error_localizacion), getString(R.string.msg_aceptar), actMapa);
            }
        }

    }
```

Now I want to move to other places to get another address but I can not.

How can I solve that?

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: When you say move - if you mean "your location" then you can do this in the emulator.  If you mean programmatically and just want to try different addresses then just modify latitude and longitude when calling 'getFromLocation' - nudge the mylocation value or just plugin actual positions.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When I say move, I mean with the finger move the location to other parts, but it's like that action is disabled. The location remains static.

Comment: I see - no you can't move your location with a finger (that would be cool).  What I'd recommend is to add a marker at your location and make it draggable and then listen for onMarkerDragListener events, specifically onMarkerDragEnd - and then employ same geocode as you do on mylocation.